# Add Text in Single Product Page On a Specific Category

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to display a text in a specific category just under the add to cart hook.

```
if ( is_product_category( 'sale' ) ) {
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'return_info' );
function return_info() {
        echo 'Note: All sale items are non returnable';
    }
}
```

I'm currently stuck with my code and it won't work. Please tell me what's wrong with it. Thank you.

Comment: Put the `if` condition inside the `return_info` function.

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'return_info' );
function return_info() {
 if ( is_product_category( 'sale' ) ) {
        echo 'Note: All sale items are non returnable';
 }
} Like this?

Comment: Yes, that's right.